# How to check average number of requests per second hitting Redis

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have a single redis pod running in my k8s cluster, and I would like to get an idea of how many requests per second my redis server is currently handling in my production environment. I have tried `redis-cli monotor`, which prints out live requests on the console but I cannot seem to find a way to get a numerical measure that simply tells me something like "redis server is handling x request per second on average in the past 24 hours". Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking across all nodes or a single node of server

Comment: @shat90 just a single pod, I only have a single instance of redis running in my k8s cluster.

Comment: did you get any results?